# Powershell - Append Group Name and Members

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that will create a CSV file with the name of the group and its members.  My script fails with the error:

The appended object does not have a property that corresponds to the following column

I am sure it is a simple mistake and I'd bang away at it but I need the data quickly.

```
$SearchBase = "OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=local"

$SPGroups = Get-ADGroup -filter * -SearchBase $SearchBase | select name

Foreach ($i in $SPGroups){
    #$Members += get-ADGroupMember -Identity $i.name | select name
    $i.name | Export-Csv -append -Path c:\bin\membersof.csv
    get-ADGroupMember -Identity $i.name | select name | Export-CSV -append -Path c:\bin\membersof.csv
    }
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$SearchBase = "OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=local"

Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $SearchBase | % {
  $group = $_.name
  Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group |
      select @{n='Group';e={$group}}, @{n='Member';e={$_.Name}}
} | Export-CSV 'C:\bin\membersof.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Create Custom Data Container
$header = @("Group,Member") #Columns
$temp = @()
$data = @()
$data += $header
$SearchBase = "OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=local"
Get-ADGroup -filter * -SearchBase $SearchBase | % {
    #For Each Group
    $Groups = $_.name
    get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groups | % {
        #For Each Member
        $Members = $_.Name
        #Add Row
        $temp = "$Groups,$Members"
        $data += $temp
    }
}
#output data to csv
$data | ConvertFrom-Csv | Export-Csv -Path c:\bin\membersof.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: When I try this code I get: Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument
or empty and then try the command again.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Both seemed to work.  I'll have to look more closely at the code to figure it out. I haven't used the % before.

Comment: BTW, any references for the above techniques would be appreciated.

Comment: % is just a foreach loop, but instead of casting it to a variable I am just piping the object. Sorry no references, I work with csv's in powershell a lot, and although the built in functions are nice, I feel the easiest way to put objects into a csv is by creating it line by line. A Csv file is just strings separated by commas. Evertime I get another Member, I format that row via temp, then add it to data.